# Change variable_itself with function

Tags: python

i want try to change variable itself with using function
like some_list.reverse().
(i want a print result 5)
how do i do?

```
b = 4
def hello(self):
    self = 5
    return None
hello(b)
print(b)
```

[sorry I uploaded wrong picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdcGe.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: when I insert a variable as a parameter and run that function, i want variable change.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data.

Comment: i realize i can upload code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Python does not work that way.  When you pass a variable to a function, you are simply passing a reference to the object that variable was bound to.  If you assign a new object to that parameter inside the function, it has no effect on the outer variable.

Now, if you pass a class object or a list or a dict, then you can change the object itself.  For example:

```
def func(xx):
    xx[0] = 5

bl = [1,2,3]
func(bl)
print(bl)
```

That prints `[5,2,3]`, because have not assigned a new object to that name.  We have changed the object whose reference was passed in.  But if we had said:

```
def func(xx):
   xx = [6,7,8]
```

that change would not be seen outside.  `xx` is now bound to a brand-new list.

Comment: Works with dictionaries too

Comment: oh! it works. I can use list or dict instead of var. and i learn one more knowledge that if i call index when object(like list) isn't declared in function, function uses global object's resource.

Comment: There's an important distinction here.  OBJECTS are neither global nor local.  Objects live in their own space.  NAMES are global or local.  In your example, the name `b` is global, and is bound to an integer object.  When you call your function, the local name `self` is bound to the same integer object.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```py
class A:
    b = 0


c = A
print()


def f(cls: A):
    cls.b = 5


print(c.b)
f(c)
print(c.b)
```

use a class.

Python use reference, just give function a different reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = 4
    
def hello():
    global b
    b = 5
    return b
    
hello()
print(b)
```